# How can I put sass loader inside app-root?

Tags: angular, sass

I want to put a loader made with scss inside app-root but I can not do this.
It doesn't work as scss style.

> I tried `<style type="text/scss">....</style>`

Comment: What do you mean by scss in `app-root`? `app-root` is your `app.component.ts` so just put your styling in `app.component.scss`?

Comment: `type="text/scss"` isn't a thing. SCSS has to be transpiled to CSS before a browser knows how to use it. Only CSS could be in `app-root` since any content child of it will get replaced after angular bootstraps. Which is why a loader often is put in there so it's available before angular is.

Comment: You didn't make a loader _just in scss,_ you used scss to style a DOM element. So make a component out of that DOM and scss, and put that component into your app.component.